# How to run through columns and rows of a table in excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on writing a data verification makro. Currently, it runs through one column and throws an error if the wrong data type is entered. The columns are dynamic because there will be new entries.

How do I run this code through several columns not only one?

```
Sub checken()

Dim i As Integer
```

Range("D4").Select

```
 Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

     If IsNumeric(ActiveCell) = False Then

         MsgBox ("A number has to be entered " & "row " & ActiveCell.Row)
        
        
     End If
    


     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

 Loop


 End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try below sub-

```
Sub CheckColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long

    lCol = Range("D4").End(xlToRight).Column
    lRow = Range("D4").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("D4", Cells(lRow, lCol))
        If IsNumeric(rng) = False Then
             MsgBox ("A number has to be entered " & "row " & rng.Row)
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```