# How to run through columns placed in the middle of a table

Tags: excel, vba

I previously asked a question regarding running through columns and rows of a table. The following code is what helped me solve the problem.

([How to run through columns and rows of a table in excel with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72853919/how-to-run-through-columns-and-rows-of-a-table-in-excel-with-vba))

In the code the Range is set by running through all the columns on the right of the C2. Now i only want to run through 3 columns to the right. This means that the value for the columns is static but the value for the rows dynamic. How can I realize this? I am grateful for any ideas!
I also included a table for visualizing the problem[image]

```
Sub CheckColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long

    lCol = Range("C2").End(xlToRight).Column
    lRow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each rng In Range("D4", Cells(lRow, lCol))
        If IsNumeric(rng) = False Then
             MsgBox ("A number has to be entered " & "row " & rng.Row)
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to know the max last row across the columns C, D, or E or do you just need to know the the last row of each column individually?

Comment: Do you need to determine the rows of C:C, **until the first empty cell** or **up to the last cell having a value**? Even if it would be annoying to send so many messages, you can try `lRow = Range("C2").End(xlUp).Row` and `For Each rng In Range("D4", Cells(lRow, "F")`. To have all the cells in the respective range, not only up to the first empty one.

Comment: Curious what you are actually trying to accomplish. Is the `MsgBox` just there as a place holder and your production code will be doing something different? If not, then it seems like raising a bunch of individually alerts 1 at a time does not seem like a very efficient solution to any problem.

Comment: There are lots of Excel functions for manipulating range and number data. Have you looked at that? What have you tried.

Comment: Just change the `lCol` setting. If you want to make it relative to cell C2, write something like `lCol = Range("C2").Offset(0,2).Column`. Note that the line `For Each rng In Range("D4", Cells(lRow, lCol))` will cover the columns from D to E. If you want to cover from C to E (starting from the 4th row), you'll need to rewrite it as `Range("C4", Cells(lRow, lCol))`.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Thank You! This is actually what I was looking for.

Comment: @urdearboy this is actually just a placeholder. I tried to simplify my question as far as possible to solve my issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the max last row across all 3 columns (C, D, E) then you can just use the `MAX` function.

Usually when finding the last used row you go from the bottom up. The code you shared is actually surfacing the first blank row which will not always be the last row.

```
Sub CheckColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<--- Update sheet name accordingly
Dim Target As Range
Dim lr As Long


'Find the MAX last row between columns C, D, E
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max( _
        ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, _
        ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, _
        ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        
        
For Each Target In Range("C2:E" & lr)
    If Not IsNumeric(Target) Then
    
        'Do what what cell is not numeric?
        
    End If
Next Target

End Sub
```